# Can we change the bounty rep requirement?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounty, privileges

Currently, you need 75 reputation to start a bounty.

However, some migrating users (meaning users that have an account with 100+ rep on another site) use this privilege a bit much.

They will sometimes start a low-ish quality question and assign a bounty to it. Can we change the bounty requirements to one of these:

- Increase bounty requirement to 150

  - **PRO:** Allows higher bounties to be made as soon as the privilege is earned.
  - **PRO:** Migrating Users need to be active on the site. They just can't bounty-n-leave. That is kinda using "free rep".
  - **PRO:** Easy to implement.
  - **CON:** Harder for new users to earn the bounty privilege.
- Make non-migrating users have a bounty requirement of 75, while migrating users require 150.

  - **PRO:** Non-Migrating users are unaffected
  - **PRO:** Migrating Users need to be active on the site
  - **CON:** Insane to implement.
  - **CON:** Is weird in comparison to rest of the rep system

I think this'll encourage users to be more active, and will make posts higher quality throughout the entire site.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen more than 20-30 featured questions on Ask Ubuntu at the same time. I'm not sure if this is worth it. Besides, the ability to create a bounty is part of the association bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really mind if a visiting user creates a bounty, gets their answer and leaves. IMHO that's one of the most useful benefits of the free rep (the other being the ability to comment<sup>1</sup>).

If I'm not normally a user of something like [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), for example, and I did have a question about English, and it didn't get enough attention, I'd like to be able to award a bounty on it.

It is, after all, rewarding my activity elsewhere (while possibly rewarding someone's activity on ELU). It's not as if I can get back the rep, or get it up to 100 again without participating in the site.

(I guess ELU is a poor choice for an example, since I believe I could contribute good quality content to ELU. [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), on the other hand, is an excellent example of where a newbie like me could do real damage with terrible advice if not downvoted in time and a place where I'd normally not answer.)

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup>(Actually, that ability to comment everywhere was the initial driving factor behind my activity on AU.)</sup></sub>